# How to find the congruence $2^{2^{19}} \equiv k \pmod{19}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the $k$, $0\leq k<19$ such that $2^{2^{19}} \equiv k  \pmod{19}$.

I found that $2^{19} \equiv 2  \pmod{19}$ but I don't know how to find $2^{2^{19}} \equiv k  \pmod{19}$. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What you really want to know is $2^{19}\bmod {18}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can start like usual, we want to reduce the exponent mod $\phi(19) = 18$
$$2^{19} \equiv 2^{7}2^{7}2^{5}\equiv 2*2* 2^5\equiv 2^7 \equiv 2\pmod {18}$$

To see why these equivalences are true, we can determine the period of $2$ mod $18$ by computing it directly:
$$2\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 16 \rightarrow -4 \rightarrow -8 \rightarrow -16 = 2$$

So $2^7 \equiv 2 \pmod {18}$, which we apply twice.

Then we can return to the original expression,
$$2^{2^{19}} \equiv 2^2  \equiv 4 \pmod {19}$$

Comment: Or the, well, I went on to compute 2^19 in my  head. Anybody here, is it an achievement to find 2^19=524288 in about 8.7 seconds(promise you,  this is true)? And then I did 524288 /18 in my head  as well. This is what I would do in a competitive exam.